# Consume only part of data in boost::asio basic_stream_socket::async_read_some handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am new into *boost::asio* so my question maight be dumb - sorry if it is such.
I am writing asynchronous server application with keepalive (multiple requests may be sent on single connection).

Connection handling routine is simple:

**In a loop**:

- schedule read request with *socket->async_read_some(buffer, handler)*
- from handler schedule write response with *async_write.*

The problem I am facing is that when 
*handler* passed to *async_read_some* is called by on of *io_service* threads, *buffers* may actually contain more data than single request (e.g. part of next request sent by client).

I do not want to (and cannot if it is only part of request) handle this remaining bytes at the moment.
I would like to do it after handling previous request is finished.

It would be easy to address this if I had the possiblity to reinject unnecessary remainging data back to the socket. So it is handled on next *async_read_some* call.

Is there such possiblity in *boost::asio* or do I have to store the remaining data somewhere aside, and handle it myself with extra code.

Answer (score 6):

I think what you are looking for is [asio::streambuf](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html).

Basically, you can inspect your seeded streambuf as a char*, read as much as you see fit, and then inform how much was *actually* processed by `consume(amount)`.

Working code-example to parse HTTP-header as a client:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace asio = boost::asio;

std::string LINE_TERMINATION = "\r\n";

class Connection {
  asio::streambuf _buf;
  asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
public:

  Connection(asio::io_service& ioSvc, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint server)
    : _socket(ioSvc)
  {
    _socket.connect(server);
    _socket.send(boost::asio::buffer("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: localhost\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n"));
    readMore();
  }

  void readMore() {
    // Allocate 13 bytes space on the end of the buffer. Evil prime number to prove algorithm works.
    asio::streambuf::mutable_buffers_type buf = _buf.prepare(13);

    // Perform read
    _socket.async_read_some(buf,  boost::bind(
          &Connection::onRead, this,
          asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, asio::placeholders::error
    ));
  }

  void onRead(size_t read, const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
    if ((!ec) && (read > 0)) {
      // Mark to buffer how much was actually read
      _buf.commit(read);

      // Use some ugly parsing to extract whole lines.
      const char* data_ = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(_buf.data());
      std::string data(data_, _buf.size());
      size_t start = 0;
      size_t end = data.find(LINE_TERMINATION, start);
      while (end < data.size()) {
        std::cout << "LINE:" << data.substr(start, end-start) << std::endl;
        start = end + LINE_TERMINATION.size();
        end = data.find(LINE_TERMINATION, start);
      }
      _buf.consume(start);

      // Wait for next data
      readMore();
    }
  }
};

int main(int, char**) {
  asio::io_service ioSvc;

  // Setup a connection and run 
  asio::ip::address localhost = asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1");
  Connection c(ioSvc, asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(localhost, 80));

  ioSvc.run();
}
```

Comment: I were just googling around for ASIO-help myself (for other, but similar needs), and found this:
http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_3_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/line_based.html

Answer (score 4):

One way of tackling this when using a reliable and ordered transport like TCP is to:

1. Write a header of known size, containing the size of the rest of the message
2. Write the rest of the message

And on the receiving end:

1. Read just enough bytes to get the header
2. Read the rest of the message and no more

Comment: Unfortunately this is not feasible as protocol is fixed and I cannot alter it :(

Comment: @losipiuk So you're saying that the protocol in it's current form doesn't contain any metadata indicating the size of the message? Are there start and end delimiters for your message? How are you determining that a message is, indeed, complete?

Comment: no - it does not contain any fixed size header. It is HTTP actually :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know the messages are going to be of a fixed length, you can do something like the following:

```
//-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
void
Connection::readMore()
{
    if (m_connected)
    {
        // Asynchronously read some data from the connection into the buffer.
        // Using shared_from_this() will prevent this Connection object from
        // being destroyed while data is being read.
        boost::asio::async_read(
            m_socket, 
            boost::asio::buffer(
                m_readMessage.getData(), 
                MessageBuffer::MESSAGE_LENGTH
            ),
            boost::bind(
                &Connection::messageBytesRead, 
                shared_from_this(), 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
            ),
            boost::bind(
                &Connection::handleRead, 
                shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );
    }
}

//-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
std::size_t
Connection::messageBytesRead(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode, 
                             std::size_t _bytesRead)
{
    return MessageBuffer::MESSAGE_LENGTH - _bytesRead;
}

//-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~-~
void
Connection::handleRead(const boost::system::error_code& _errorCode)
{
    if (!_errorCode)
    {
        /// Do something with the populated m_readMessage here.
        readMore();
    }
    else
    {
        disconnect();
    }
}
```

The `messageBytesRead` callback will indicate to `boost::asio::async_read` when a complete message has been read.  This snippet was pulled from an existing `Connection` object from running code, so I know it works...